# how to perform backup in informix using onbar and primary storage manager?

Tags: database, informix, database-backups

I would like to know how to configure primary storage manager and onbar to backup system and dbspaces so that I can restore when ever necessary.

Comment: That's a very broad question.  I'm not sure there's a succinct answer.  How big is the system you're planning to backup (the dbspaces etc for the Informix server)?  When you say 'backup system' (in the sense 'verb + noun' rather than 'adjective + noun'), what do you mean?  How should you backup your o/s — or, at least, the INFORMIXDIR?  Or what?  Presumably you're using Informix 12.10 (for some detailed version such as 12.10.FC7); on which platform?

Comment: I use 12.10 in Linux platform , I've used ontape utility till now , I want to use  onbar and PSM  considering advantages of onbar as this can backup individual dbspaces , whole system and other objects as well.

Comment: You should look at the Informix [Backup and Restore Guide](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.bar.doc/bar.htm) generally, and the [PSM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.bar.doc/ids_bar_526.htm) section in particular.